# Windows apps xaml data binding for style

Tags: c++, xaml, c++-cx, uwp

I'm loading xaml directly in C++/CX and I have a problem that I want to access the properties that are described on xaml and modify them. This is how I apply style to control:

```
switchControl->Style = makeSwitchControlStyle();
```

And that function simply uses xaml reader to load the xaml string below:

```
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ToggleSwitch}" TargetType="ToggleSwitch">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="154"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleSwitch">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Width="52" Height="23">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchCurtain">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchCurtainPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchTrackPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnob">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnob">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchCurtain">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchCurtainPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchTrackPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnob">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchThumbPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnob">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchThumbPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchOuterBorderDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchTrackDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnob">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnob">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchThumbDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchCurtain">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchCurtainDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ToggleStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="DraggingToOnTransition" From="Dragging" GeneratedDuration="0" To="On">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobCurrentToOnOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.CurtainCurrentToOnOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchCurtain"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="DraggingToOffTransition" From="Dragging" GeneratedDuration="0" To="Off">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobCurrentToOffOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.CurtainCurrentToOffOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchCurtain"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="OnToOffTransition" From="On" GeneratedDuration="0" To="Off">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobOnToOffOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.CurtainOnToOffOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchCurtain"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="OffToOnTransition" From="Off" GeneratedDuration="0" To="On">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobOffToOnOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.CurtainOffToOnOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchCurtain"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Dragging"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Off">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-44" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="CurtainTranslateTransform"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="On">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="CurtainTranslateTransform"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="38" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="KnobTranslateTransform"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ContentStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="OffContent"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OnContent"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="SwitchKnobBounds" Height="19" Width="50">
                            <Border x:Name="OuterBorder" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchOuterBorderBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="2">
                                <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchTrackBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchTrackBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="SwitchCurtainBounds">
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="SwitchCurtainClip">
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="SwitchCurtain" Fill="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchCurtainBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="44">
                                                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="CurtainTranslateTransform" X="-44"/>
                                                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                            </Rectangle>
                                        </ContentPresenter>
                                    </ContentPresenter>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="SwitchKnob" Fill="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stroke="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchThumbBorderThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Width="12">
                                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="KnobTranslateTransform"/>
                                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" Margin="-3" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" Margin="-3" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                            <Grid Margin="0,0,50,19">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Now, this is a cut template of the original ToggleSwitch without extraneous labels and it looks like this:

[image: ToggleSwitch]

I would like to expose method which wraps this class that could set, for instance, the color of a knob to blue/red etc. and similar things for other components of the original toggleswitch.

So, how do I set specific properties for control after I've loaded the style from hardcoded xaml string? How do I refer to properties from the style?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You normally would extend the control and add your own control template on which you can change colors etc. `ToggleSwitch` is sealed so you can't do this. You must create a separate style with new colors.

Another approach could be to create a `ToggleSwitch` style factory.

Comment: Don't say *you can't* yet. How about creating attached properties to control the native properties? Or update the resource brushes' `Color` properties?